# Not understanding what is going on in this problem (evaluating a logarithm)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\log({ \log }_{ 10 }10000)$$

Steps I took to solve this:

${ \log }_{ 10 }10000=4$

${ \log }_{ 10 }4=y$

$10^{ y }=4$

${ \log }10^{ y }=\log 4$

$y=\frac { \log 4 }{ \log 10 } $

doesn't seem to come out to the correct answer...

Comment: Note that $\log 10 = 1$.

Comment: yes, so when I evaluate it one step further, it goes back to equaling $log4$ and $log4$ is not the correct answer

Comment: It is correct; you can test it with your calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct since
$$\log (\log (10000)) = \log (\log (10^4)) = \log(4\log(10)) = \log 4$$

Comment: why does the answer key state $4$ is the answer then?

Comment: Either a mistake in the book or you misunderstood the question?

Comment: The book must be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$y=\log_{10}4=\frac{\log 4}{\log 10}=\log 4$

Answer (score 2):

$\log({ \log }_{ 10 }10000)$

$=\log_{10} ( \log_{10} 10^4)$

$=\log_{10} (4 \log_{10} 10)$

$=\log_{10}4$

Yours is correct.